# How to use the IDS peak python API

Tags: python, api, ids

I have just started to work with a camera from IDS Imaging and I am trying to use the Python API of the IDS Peak software.
I can access the camera to get the vendor information etc. but unfortunately I am not able to properly access the data stream to get the actual pictures.
The documentation has no examples on how to use the API and because of this I am kinda lost on how to approach this.
I know that I need to start the acquisition, buffer data and than read that data. But I have no idea how to do that in code.
If anybody as some experience working with IDS cameras, some pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to get started with the IDS Peak API in Python, you can have a look at the two code samples that come with the installation of IDS Peak. They are located in the installation folder: C:\Program Files\IDS\ids_peak\sdk\samples\source\peak\python

Also, in the new manual for IDS Peak, there are code snippets for every function call - for most of the functions, the snippets are also available in Python.

In addition, you can find information about the basic principles of programming with the IDS Peak API in the manual:
https://de.ids-imaging.com/manuals/ids-peak/ids-peak-user-manual/1.3.0/en/program-procedure.html